# Apache Web Server Folder Permission On Windows7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, permissions

I have an Apache Web server and my own CMS on this server. I don't want to show my directory listing to everybody, and I want set permission to hide my files like this alert:

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin/ on this server.
```

I know how I can give permission to folder with security. But I don't know which permission is for this and which user must deny this permission.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that with a .htaccess file.. make a .htaccess file with a unix based editor like Notepad++ and copy the following in it. and save tha file in any folder you want!

```
deny from all
```

Comment: You're welcome.. So please accept the answer so people will know that it has worked..! thx